# Bigrams as map keys in C++

Tags: c++

Alright, so I'm wondering how I would go about creating a map key from a two word string (a bigram). For example, the line "This is only a test." would contain the bigrams "this is", "is only", "only a", and "a test."

I'm thinking of using make_pair, but something tells me this could cause these bigrams to be created out of order. Would this be the case? If not, would this pairing approach be on the right track?

Comment: You could use almost any data structure to store a bigram. A `std::vector<std::string>`, `std::tuple<std::string, std::string>`/`std::pair<std::string, std::string>`, `std::list<std::string>`, etc. are all valid and reasonable choices depending on what you want to do with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend a `std::pair` because it's inherently binary. If there's a chance you need trigrams or 4-grams, you might want to stick to a `std::tuple`, which is a generalization of `std::pair` (informally speaking).

So long as your bigram algorithm is correct, the order will be preserved. There are some obvious improvements which could be made, but I wrote a quick implementation here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <utility>

std::vector<std::string> tokenize(const std::string& s) {
    std::istringstream iss(s);

    std::vector<std::string> v{std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss),
                               std::istream_iterator<std::string>()};
    return v;
}

std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> make_bigrams(const std::vector<std::string>& tokens) {
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> bigrams;
    for(auto it = std::cbegin(tokens); it != std::prev(std::cend(tokens)); ++it) {
        bigrams.push_back(std::make_pair(*it, *std::next(it)));
    }
    return bigrams;
}

std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> sentence_bigram(const std::string& s) {
    const auto toks = tokenize(s);
    return make_bigrams(toks);
}

int main() {
    const auto& bigrams = sentence_bigram("hello, world. my name is erip");
    std::map<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, int> m;
    for(const auto& e: bigrams) {
       std::cout << "Adding (" << e.first << "), (" << e.second << ") to the map.\n";
       m[e] = 0;
    }
}
```

and you can see it in action [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/41483c36dd49a5ca).

Comment: Thanks for the assistance! Appreciate your help!